# Duplicate (multiple) .emlx copies of the same email messages

Tags: mail.app, email, messages

I have just updated my iMac (mid 2015) from Yosemite to Big Sur  and I am still going through import and clean up of years and years of email messages, coming from various older Macs I owned in the past.

Now I realize that I have many duplicate copies of these old messages and attachments, which slow down the Mail app and take up disk space.

When I am in the Mail app, any selected mail box only shows one copy of each message with its own received date, size etc...
However, when I open the same mailbox in  the ~Library/Mail/V8/ folder I find multiple copies of each message in the .emlx file format.

As an example: in Mail I have one mailbox showing 13 messages but when I open this mailbox folder in ~Library/Mail/V8/ I find 24 different .emlx files resulting from duplicate versions of the same message.

Oddly (for me) each copy of the same message has a slightly different file size and checksum. I can tell they are the duplicates of the same message only by opening each .emlx file manually in Mail. This is also confirmed in the Info window, since different emlx files have the same "content created on" date and time.

None of the duplicate finder apps I tested can spot these multiple duplicates.

The additional problem is that the attachments to the duplicate messages are stored in separate "attachment" folders

QUESTION: Could you please suggest a solution to find and remove message and attachment duplicates?

Thank you,
Stefano